# SonarQube support for .sqlproj and .dtproj

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sonarqube

We have an active SonarQube Version 6.0 installation that is inspecting numerous C# projects e.g. those with a .csproj extension. If the .csproj contains a sql file then this file will be inspected.

In a new solution we have a mixture of .csproj, .dtproj and .sqlproj projects. Only the .csproj projects are being inspected by SonarQube even though much of the .sqlproj is made up of sql files.

Can SonarQube inspect files in .sqlproj and/or .dtproj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server projects are currently not supported by the *SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild*. You can track progress on this via ticket [SONARMSBRU-243](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-243).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try and come up with a work around in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the issue I created a dummy csproj that only exists to pull in all the sql files from all the database projects using a wildcard in the ItemGroup e.g.

`<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="**\*.sql" />
</ItemGroup>`

Including this project in the solution and passing this to Sonar means that the sql files in the projects are inspected.

The full csproj is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A1DE4897-3BBB-4F67-8D97-662793603C18}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Dummy.Sonar</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Dummy.Sonar</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreGeneratedCode>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreGeneratedCode>
    <NoWarn>2210</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="**\*.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Do you mind pasting the content of dummy csproj here ?

Comment: Hi @matt, Thanks for the work around but here my doubt is if any sql file present in the some other .csproj of the same sln will be analysed twice right?... as per the workaround. Please correct me if am wrong...